# Startup and Shutdown order of WSO2 Components

Tags: api, wso2, sequence, startup, shutdown

On a non-production instance and on a single host, I happened to install WSO2 Components such as WSO2 Identity Server and WSO2 API Manager.

What is the order of Startup and Shutdown?

If I understand correctly, is the below order is up to the mark to avoid any internal server errors?

**Startup**:

1. WSO2- Identity Server
2. WSO2 API Manager

**Shutdown**:

1. WSO2 API Manager
2. WSO2 Identity Server
3. Kill any dangling requests

Experts please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start both the services (WSO2 APIM and WSO2 IS) on a single server, try changing the port offset of anyone in the carbon.xml located in /repository/conf
`

```
    <!-- Ports offset. This entry will set the value of the ports defined below to
     the define value + Offset.
     e.g. Offset=2 and HTTPS port=9443 will set the effective HTTPS port to 9445
     -->
    <Offset>0</Offset>`
```

In case of using an Identity server as a key manager, the identity server should be started first, followed by API-Manager. or if you have done any configuration where you have placed the URL of one of the services into another service, then the URL that you have used needs to be in UP state. so that service should be started first. for example, in case of identity as a key manager, you put the URL of the identity server in the api-manager.xml file of APIM, so in this case, WSO2 Identity server should be started first.

Only if there is any connectivity between the 2 services (application-wise not Database related), then only the order of starting the services matters

Hope this clears your confusion